# Making a scrollbar in Flash with a position property and a move event

Tags: flash, events, position, scrollbar

I want to realize a horizontal Scrollbar in Flash to control an object of my page.
I need to be able to get/set the scrolling position and to catch the event when the scrollbar move.
As far as I understand, the UIScrollBar object have to be attached to Textfield and there is not access to the position property and the move event.

Is there a simple and free script which do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScrollPane native component, which can do everything you've mentioned. You can also use [Kirupa Scrollbar](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?275991-Kirupa-Scrollbar-AS3-0).